# PostgreSQL 10 - view current logs on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, logging, psycopg2

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/j4QvrC_FuOI

The following statements are from the above link (using Psycopg2):

```
>> pool=ThreadedConnectionPool(0,5,<connection_args>) 
>> conn1=pool.getconn() 
>> conn2=pool.getconn() 
>> pool.putconn(conn1) 
>> pool.putconn(conn2) 
>> conn3=pool.getconn() 
>> pool.putconn(conn3) 

2017-06-02 14:30:26 AKDT LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=64786 
2017-06-02 14:30:26 AKDT LOG:  connection authorized: user=logger database=flightlogs 
2017-06-02 14:30:35 AKDT LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=64788 
2017-06-02 14:30:35 AKDT LOG:  connection authorized: user=logger database=flightlogs 
2017-06-02 14:30:46 AKDT LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:19.293 user=logger database=flightlogs host=::1 port=64786 
2017-06-02 14:30:53 AKDT LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:17.822 user=logger database=flightlogs host=::1 port=64788 
2017-06-02 14:31:15 AKDT LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=64790 
2017-06-02 14:31:15 AKDT LOG:  connection authorized: user=logger database=flightlogs 
2017-06-02 14:31:20 AKDT LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:05.078 user=logger database=flightlogs host=::1 port=64790
```

Where can I view these logs? I went to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\log` and checked out the log text files, and it doesn't seem that it has the most recent log records. How can I view the log updates in real-time whenever I run SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

My logs are in ..data\pg_log folder
If yours are not showing the sql that you require you probably have to turn on logging in your postgresql.conf file

```
#log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

You need to restart Postgresql if you change logging